# Group numbers into different ranges

Tags: kotlin, mapping

I'm new to Kotlin and I'm trying to solve some problem.
I have a list with the following object:

```
data class Route(duration: Int)
```

I want to create a map that will group those trips according to the range of the duration (e.g. 0-9 are single group, 10-19 the next, 20-29, and so on...)

for example, the result of this list:

```
listOf(Route(5), Route(7), Route(31))
```

should be the following map:

```
0..9 to listOf(Route(5), Route(7))
30..39 to listOf(Route(31))
```

I searched and I've seen that I can put the range into `groupBy` - however, this is a const range. how can I group by different ranges?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the groupBy function to do that.

```kotlin
fun createRangeOfTen(number: Int): IntRange {
    val trunc = number / 10
    val lowerBound = trunc * 10
    val upperBound = lowerBound + 9

    return lowerBound..upperBound
}

val list = listOf(
    Route(5), Route(7), Route(31)
)
val map = list.groupBy({ createRangeOfTen(it.duration) }, { it })
println(map)
// {0..9=[Route(duration=5), Route(duration=7)], 30..39=[Route(duration=31)]}
```

Comment: If it wasn't clear from the question I don't know the content of the list so I cannot use simple mapOf(), that's why I wanted to use groupBy {}